# How to print ftp file information using curl and printf

Tags: linux, bash, curl, awk, grep

I am trying to get file information for batch downloading and having difficulty with pipes to printf.

Test case

```sh
$ curl -sI ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/README.ftp
```

```
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Aug 2015 15:47:26 GMT
Content-Length: 2037
Accept-ranges: bytes
```

A simple grep to cut that is working for file size

```sh
$ curl -sI ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/README.ftp | grep Content-Length | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

```
2037
```

Grep to cut is working for file date and time

```sh
$ curl -sI ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/README.ftp | grep Last-Modified | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6
```

```
12 Aug 2015 15:47:26
```

However, extending grep to cut to printf is not working for the server file date and time, printf is return the local system date and time?

```sh
$ curl -sI ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/README.ftp | grep Last-Modified | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6 | printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T '
```

Local date and time, not remote date and time?

```
2019-08-24 20:32:53
```

The file size and date will be used in scripts for batch downloads and custom logging. Something along these lines...

```
infilesize=$(curl -sI $inpath/$infile | grep Content-Length | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
infiledate=$(curl -sI $inpath/$infile | grep Last-Modified | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6 | printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T ' )
printf $infilesize 2>&1 | tee -a $logpath/$logfile
printf $infiledate 2>&1 | tee -a $logpath/$logfile
```

My first hurdle is fix the pipe syntax for printf?

Open to other pipe approaches, sed and awk.

Relatively inexperienced with bash, so appreciate verbose code suggestions and or elegant code and explanations, wanting to learn good techniques.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

The `date` subshell approach is working for remote server file date and time.

However, I am now having problems with `printf` to output multiple variables on a single line. I have had a look around but having difficult understanding the arguments handling for printf and receiving unexpected results.

```sh
printf $infilename $infilesize $infiledate 2>&1 | tee -a $outpath/$logfile.txt
```

This has been asked as a separate question [How can I print multiple variables using printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642052/how-can-i-print-multiple-variables-using-printf)

Comment: printf ignores stdin.

Comment: `printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T'` prints always current time. What Do you want to do with cut's output (e.g. `12 Aug 2015 15:47:26`)?

Comment: convert the cut's output from `12 Aug 2015 15:47:26` to `2015-08-12 15:47:26`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need `printf`, just use a subshell from `date` to display the `cut` date information:

```
curl -sI ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/README.ftp | grep Last-Modified | \
date -d "$(cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6)" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%ST"
```

**Result:**

```
2015-08-12 15:47:26T
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. just what I needed. Had read printf was preferred for date and time directives over date for bash 4.x. But didn't appreciate there was limitations with stdin.