# How can I print multiple variables using printf

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am trying get `printf` to output multiple variables on a single line.

Having difficultly with argument handling and formats for `printf` and receiving unexpected results.

**Code snippet**

```sh
printf '%s %s %s' $infile $insize $indate 2>&1 | tee -a $logfile
find $infile -printf ' %p %s %CY-%Cm-%Cd %CH:%CM:%.2TS \n' 2>&1 | tee -a $logfile
```

**Unexpected result**
* first file size not showing, date and time not correct (printf)
* second file size correct, date and time not correct (find -printf)

```sh
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/README.ftp 2019-08-25 00:00:00 ./README.ftp 2037 2019-08-25 14:22:26
```

**Expected result**

```sh
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/README.ftp 2037 2015-08-12 15:47:26 ./README.ftp 2037 2019-08-24 20:32:53
```

**Remote file**

```sh
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Aug 2015 15:47:26 GMT
Content-Length: 2037
```

**Local file**

```sh
2037 Aug 13  2015 README.ftp
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at `help printf`.

Comment: `man 1 printf` is probably more informative. The critical thing is that `printf`'s first argument is a *format string* that tells it how to format what it prints; the remaining arguments are the things to print. Also, put double-quotes around variable references (e.g. `"$inpath/$infile.gz"` instead of just `$inpath/$infile.gz`) to prevent unexpected parsing.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `printf '%s %s %s\n' $inpath/$infile.gz $infilesize $infiledate` and then show us the output you want?

Comment: *$infilesize* perhaps requires **%d**.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for the `man 1 printf` reference was informative. And for the double quotes handling advice, have tidied up variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```sh
printf '%s %d %s' "$infile" "$insize" "$indate" 2>&1 | tee -a "$logfile"
find "$infile" -printf ' %p %s %CY-%Cm-%Cd %CH:%CM:%.2TS \n' 2>&1 | tee -a "$logfile"
```

**Result**

```sh
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/README.ftp 2037 2015-08-12 15:47:26 ./README.ftp 2037 2019-08-24 20:32:53
```

`man 1 printf` clear and simple explanation of argument handing.

GNU Manual Table of Output Conversions for [format summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Table-of-Output-Conversions.html#Table-of-Output-Conversions)

Comment: You should probably still [quote your variables.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)